# Controlling access to specific files via <location>

Tags: asp.net, authentication, asp.net-membership, forms-authentication, authorization

A) We can also control access to specific files using `<location>` tags. Why aren’t  `<location>` elements contained inside `<system.web>` tag, but are instead nested directly inside `<configuration>` element?

B) I realize `<system.web>` element is used for Asp.Net settings, but why does `<location>`  also contain `<system.web>`? Is it so that it specifies settings specified inside `<system.web>`are applied only for when file is included in Asp.Net application?

If so, then that would suggest that `<location>` element could be used for non-Asp.Net applications also?

thanx

Answer (score 1):

The thing is that `<system.web>` is not the only element that affects ASP.NET applications. `<location>` can override some of the defaults for certain pages. Here's a sample from MSDN:

```
<configuration>
    <location path="UploadPage.aspx">
        <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="128"/>
    </location>
</configuration>
```

Comment: But still, why isn't <location>  contained inside <system.web>? Is it ( as McBee suggested ) due to <location> also being used for non-Asp.Net applications?

Answer (score 1):

*guessing wildly*

was almost certainly meant to be bound up with Code Access Security, which can use URLs as a membership condition for a code group. I don't think this was fully expressed or implemented in .NET, but it means the same schema could have been used for non-ASP.NET scenarios.